# Get Web.config value through jquery

Tags: jquery, ios, get, web-config, using

Can I read data from web.config using JQuery ?

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="Phone" value="1"/>
   <add key="Fax" value="1"/>
</appSettings>
```

I need to get Phone value through jquery

Comment: have look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056827/how-to-read-web-config-app-key-settings-in-html-markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a webservice that returns the values for you. You dont have direct access to the web.config from javascript

Answer (score 0):

The web.config lives on the serverside. jQuery lives on the clientside, so either you expose a webservice, or you simply provide the need values from the webconfig to the client by adding them to the DOM.